# Ignoring an InterruptedException properly

Tags: java

I am aware that ignoring an InterruptedException is actually a bad practice. But let's assume in my case it is necessary: it is a utils method in a deep place, which is called by different threads. Please also assume it is not possible to rethrow.

If my only option is to tell the system "ok, I will not sleep any further, but I cannot kill this thread myself. I will finish my job and hope that my caller takes care of your interruption request", is this the correct way of doing it?

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // ignore
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Does the method interrupt() do anything else other than resetting the interrupted flag?

Answer (score -1):

> Please also assume it is not possible to rethrow.

Impossible; you can always rethrow. `throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);` is never a compile time error - that should be your default choice for "I have no idea what this exceptions means or I cant be bothered to handle it". It's perfectly fine: It ensures that the code will be rolled up properly, you want that to happen when exceptions you can't handle / weren't expecting (heh) occur.

However, in this case, uniquely, 'I did not expect it' also means it cannot possibly happen.

> InterruptedException

Note that *InterruptedException* **cannot ever happen** unless some code is **explicitly** doing it. You do not get interrupted when the system is running low on resources and needs you to clean up. You do not get interrupted because some code in java core or any third party library decided to interrupt you for funsies. You do not get interrupted when the user hits CTRL+C, or goes into the task manager and clicks 'end process'.

There is **only one** way to be interrupted, and it is when some java code running in your JVM process runs: `yourThread.interrupt();`.

Presumably, there are only two options:

[A] You never do this. The point is moot. Rethrow that thing using `throw new RuntimeException(e);` - you're writing code that is literally going to never ever run, stop worrying about it.

[B] You invoked `interrupt()`, explicitly. I assume it wasn't because the cat strolled on the keyboard :) - You had some intent by doing it. So, what is the intent? Whatever you intended to happen, program it in the catch block. The usual options are either to abort a thread entirely (so, just `return;`), or if you have a loop that sleeps, checks something, sleeps again, etc - to recheck (a poor man's wait/notify setup, in other words), or to re-read some configuration or otherwise re-perform some initialization procedure. It's up to you. There is no described style or rule.

> Does the method interrupt() do anything else other than resetting the interrupted flag?

Yes, it returns true or false depending on whether it was up or not. But this is completely pointless. **Everything** in java that can throw InterruptedException +lowers that flag first_. There is therefore absolutely no point whatsoever in lowering the flag in the catch block - it has already been lowered if you ever get there. You EITHER get the flag raised on you, OR you get an InterruptedException (the flag is there because not everything throws InterruptedEx). Note that if your thread is sleeping due to some sleeping op that is not declared to throws InterruptedException, then it may interrupt or not - it depends on the OS capabilities. For example, if you're waiting for network traffic (e.g. calling `read()` on an `InputStream` derived from a `java.net.Socket` or whatnot), then interrupted the thread may either do nothing at all other than raise the flag, or, it will actually end up shutting down the threadsleep. In that case, the code in that InputStream **will** lower the flag and ends up throwing some sort of IOException (because it can't throw InterruptedException; InterruptedException is checked, and read() doesn't declare it).

Note that if the flag is raised, and you invoke any method that is specced to throw InterruptedException, said method will act **IMMEDIATELY**, it never goes to sleep in the first place. It lowers the flag and throws InterruptedException, instantly.

Therefore you rarely need to check the flag - very few threads lack a looping  construct and very few threads will chug on for a long time without ever invoking anything that will end up invoking `Thread.sleep()` or `obj.wait()` somewhere along the line.

NB: The intent of the `interrupted()` method is to use it as the sole condition in a busy loop that doesn't otherwise call any code that would throw InterruptedException. e.g.:

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    doSomethingThatNeverSleeps();
}
```

that'd be the whole body of your `run()` method. That will keep running forever and make your CPU fans make the laptop take off, at least until some other code tells the thread to call it a day by invoking `.interupt()`. As I said, rare that you need this construct, but that's what it is for.

Comment: When you write "lower the flag", does that mean it's cleared / set to false? I read your post twice. Perhaps it's because I'm not a native English speaker, but I found it very difficult to understand.

Comment: I actually understand the mere of it, but it somehow ignores the question.

Comment: 'lowered the flag' means 'set to false', yes.